# Send array of mpz_t over mpi

Tags: data-structures, mpi, gmp

I use a libgmp (GMP) to work with very long integers, stored as `mpz_t`: http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Internals.html#Integer-Internals

> `mpz_t` variables represent integers using sign and magnitude, in space dynamically allocated and reallocated.

So I think `mpz_t` is like pointer.

How can I send an array of `mpz_t` variables with data over MPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
unsigned long *buf, *t; // pointers for ulong array for storing gmp data
unsigned long count, countc; // sizes of data and element sizes array 
unsigned long size = array_size; // size of array
size_t *bc,*tc; // pointers for size_t array to store element sizes;

buf=(unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*(size*limb_per_element));
bc=(size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t)*(size));

if(rank==SENDER_RANK) {
    t=buf;
    tc=bc;
    for(int i;i<size;i++) {
        mpz_export(t,tc,1,sizeof(unsigned long),0,0, ARRAY(i));
        t+=*tc;
    tc++;
    }
    count=t-buf;
    countc=tc-bc;
    MPI_Send(&count, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&countc, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(bc, countc*(sizeof(size_t)), MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(buf, count, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else {
    status=MPI_Recv(&count, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, SENDER_RANK, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL); 
    status=MPI_Recv(&countc, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, SENDER_RANK, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL); 
    t=buf;
    tc=bc;
    status=MPI_Recv(bc, countc*(sizeof(size_t)), MPI_CHAR, SENDER_RANK, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL); 
    status=MPI_Recv(buf, count, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, SENDER_RANK, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL); 
    for(int i; i<size; i++) {
        mpz_import(ARRAY(i),*tc,1,sizeof(unsigned long),0,0, t);
        t+=*tc;
        tc++;
    }
}
free(buf);
free(bc);
```

Comment: as I understand it, this will not work for negative integers. `mpz_export` does not export the sign of the integer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`mpz_import()` and `mpz_export()`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#Integer-Import-and-Export) to convert between `mpz_t` and e.g. `char` arrays, which you can then send/receive over MPI. Be careful with getting the parameters related to endianness etc. right.

Comment: How can I export an array of `mpz_t`s ?

Comment: I don't know if there is built-in support for that, so you might need to allocate an array that is large enough to hold all of the numbers, and then repeatedly call `mpz_export()` and gradually fill the array. You might also be able to use [`mpz_out_raw()` and `mpz_inp_raw()`](http://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html#I_002fO-of-Integers) if there is a way to create memory streams in C.

Comment: i just found that I must pass two arrays - first is output of export and second is array of `count`s returned by export!

Comment: @osgx: I forgot to think about that. An alternative solution would be to interleave the counts with the export data: the first four bytes contain an `int` that represents the first count, then follow that many bytes that represent the first number, then another four bytes that represent the second count, and so on.